# How to open 100 file with one proccess?

Tags: linux, pid, ulimit

I know the output of `ulimit -S -n` is the number of `fd` that a process can handle or create. How can I open files more than that number to reach the limit of my system with one process ID?

Comment: The usual limit is 1024, so how comes yours is 100? Is your computer controlled by someone else?

Comment: No .I want to reach the number of limit in openfiles for one proccess .so with ulimt -n 100 , changed default number .

Comment: Why not set it to some arbitrarily large value? Your system will be able to handle a _lot_ of file descriptors, probably more than your single process would ever need or could practically use

Comment: I just want to see what's happen when I reach to the limit . in fact I want to find the threshold for my server .